# How to enable button if user clicked to the checkbutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

This is my code

```
def register_user():

        Button(win, text="Sign Up", command=register_file, state=DISABLED).place(x=20, y=290) 
        var = IntVar()
        Checkbutton(win, variable=var,).place(x=15, y=249)
```

How can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy, you can use the `command` option of `Checkbutton` to get a func to trigger each time you select or unselect the checkbox, like:

```
def register_user():
        def enable(*args):
            if var.get(): #if the checkbutton is tick
                b['state'] = 'normal' #enable the button
            else: #else
                b['state'] = 'disabled' #disable it

        but = Button(win, text="Sign Up", command=register_file, state=DISABLED)
        but.place(x=20, y=290) 
        var = IntVar()
        cb = Checkbutton(win, variable=var,command=enable) #command option triggers the enable
        cb.place(x=15, y=249)
```

Why am I saying assigning variables and `place()` on another line? This is so that the widgets don't becomes `None`.

> The grid, pack and place functions of the Entry object and of all other widgets returns None. In python when you do a().b(), the result of the expression is whatever b() returns, therefore Entry(...).grid(...) will return None.

To understand better take a read from its source, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)